SQL query to select average salary for each employee
When I tried to select employee fname,lname, salary and the average of the salary it returned the same number for all employee.
here what I typed to query:
SELECT 
    Fname AS EmployeeFirstName, 
    Lname AS EmployeeLastName, 
    Salary AS Sal, 
    (SELECT AVG(Salary) FROM Employee) AS AverageSalary,
FROM 
    Employee;

And this is the screenshot of the result:

I want the average be counted for each employee salary, any idea?

Is Employee a table that has multiple records per employee, each with a different (historical…?) salary?

yes as shown the salary is different from an employee to another, i didn't understand historical?

The average employee salary doesn't change according to which employee you show it next to. It is just the sum of all salaries divided by number of employees

You shall use GROUP BY clause.
SELECT 
    Fname AS EmployeeFirstName, 
    Lname AS EmployeeLastName, 
    AVG(Salary) AS Sal
FROM  Employee
GROUP BY employeeId; -- Replace this by the column id specific to the employees

Note: You'll need to set sql_mode to "only_full_group_by" or "" (empty).
For instance, you might do:
SET sql_mode = '';

See this answer for more information

Column 'Employee.Fname ' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. this error appears.

You need to set sql_mode. I updated my answer with more details

Please update your question with your new complete query and the error message
